# Finding the adherent points of $A=\left\{\left(1/n,1/m\right)|n,m\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis

The obvious adherent point is $(0,0),$ then I thought about fixing a point for each component and finding the adherent points on each line, but it leaves a mess.
Doing it "my way" would lead to find out that the derived set is
$$\left\{\left(0,0\right)\right\}\cup\left\{\left(1/n,0\right)|n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} \cup\left \{\left(0,1/m\right)|m\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B=\{(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{m})|n,m\in \mathbb N\}$

First we prove all points of the form $(0,\frac{1}{b})$ and $(\frac{1}{a},0)$ are adherent points. This is straightworward. Given the point $(0,\frac{1}{b})$, where $b$ is fixed, consider all of the points $(\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{b})$. What is the distance between the two points? It is $\frac{1}{m}$, therefore no matter what open ball around $(0,\frac{1}{b})$ we take there will always be a point $(\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{b})$ inside that ball. The case $(\frac{1}{a},0)$ is analogous. It is also easy to see $(0,0)$ is an adherent point, as you noted.

We will now prove these are the only points, the proof relies on the following fact: The distance between a real $x$ and the set $A=\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in \mathbb R\}$ different to $x$ is always greater than $0$ except if $x$ is zero. The proof when $x$ is negative is straightforward, the proof when $x$ is greater than $1$ is also trivial and finally the proof when $x$ is between $0$ and $1$ can be seen because $x$ is between  $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$ when $x$ is not in $A$ and $x$ is between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+2}$ when $x=\frac{1}{n}$. In any case the distance between $x$ and $A$ is going to be the minimum of these distances.

Using this result we can see the distance between $(0,y)$ and $B$ where $y$ is not $\frac{1}{n}$ and any other point of $B$ is not zero. This is because the distance is greater than the distance between $y$ and $A$ which is greater than zero. Since the distance is positive, let the distance be $\delta$. Then $B((0,y),\delta)$ is an open ball that does not intersect $B$ . So $(0,y)$ is not an adherent point, analogously $(x,0)$ is not an adherent point when $x$ is not of the form $\frac{1}{n}$.

We now show the point $(x,y)$ when $x,y\neq 0$ is not an adherent point. To see this notice the distance between $(x,y)$ and a point in $B$ other than $(x,y)$ is larger than or equal to the minimum of the following two distances: The distance between $x$ and a number of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ other than itself and the distance between $y$ and a number of the form $\frac{1}{m}$ other than itself. Since these two numbers are positive (because $x$ and $y$ are not zero) the minimum is positive. So the distance betwen $(x,y)$ and $B\setminus\{(x,y)\}$ is a real positive number $\delta$. Therefore the open ball $B((x,y),\delta)$ does not contain any points of $B$ expect possibly $(x,y)$. This proves $(x,y)$ is not an adherent point.

So the adherent points of $B$ are those of the form $(0,\frac{1}{m}),(\frac{1}{n},0)$ and $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will write down the details on my own style.
This topic is being hard for me. At least I think I'm staring to understand it.

Comment: I had a small typo. I fixed it,